# Some confusion about where vectors emanate from,

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

Take the plane x+y+z=0, for example.  Then the vectors (0,0,0), (1,-1,0), (1,0,-1) "lie on this plane."  And to find a normal to this plane, just compute the cross-product of any two independent vectors from this plane.

But are the vectors "on this plane" emanating from the origin?  I'm pretty sure it is not.  And, the normal vector, (1,1,1), emanates from the plane, not from the origin.  Or, a unit normal for a sphere, sits on the sphere, and doesn't start from the origin.

So my question is ...what do the numbers in these vectors actually mean?  What would (1,-1,0) mean?  Is it still 1 unit in the x direction, -1 unit in the y direction, and 0 units in the z direction?

Thanks,

Comment: If you translate your vector that `emanates' form the origin to some other point, it's still the same vector.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Kaster :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using vectors to describe **position**, as in your three vectors, they describe the position obtained by moving **from origin** by the amount and direction given by the vector. Describing the normal vector to a plane is just the usual notion of vector as a **motion** with direction and length.

Comment: Hi @user21820, then the normal vector for my example, n = (1,1,1), which I understand how to get arithmetically, emanates from the plane, and **from** the plane, moves 1 unit each in the x,y,z directions?  If I drew the vector (1,1,1) out on paper, emanating from the origin, it would certainly not look normal to the plane x+y+z=0, which I have checked out on Wolfram.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: Yes to your first question. You cannot visualize a 3d object on paper unless you are good enough with visualizing projections. Imagine the points in the space in front of you and imagine the plane passing through (1,0,0) and (0,1,0) and (0,0,1) and see that (1,1,1) is indeed perpendicular to that plane. Don't use Wolfram unless you know how to use it. It is full of mistakes and misleading answers.

Comment: Similarly with the three points you have it will be the same thing. I chose a different three points because it's an easier example.

Comment: Ok, got it.  Thanks for your time, @user21820 - have a great night :-)

Comment: @LebronJames: You're welcome. It's afternoon where I am. =)

Comment: Ah, lucky.  It's almost 2am here :-(  Have a great afternoon!!